# fluid (non-discrete) scrolling with carouFredSel

Tags: caroufredsel

I have set up mousewheel support like this:

```
mousewheel: {
    items: 1,
    easing: 'linear',
    duration: 100,
    queue: 'last'
}
```

The problem is that I would like scrolling by mousewheel to be non-discrete. Atm. the minimum shift when scrolling is by height of an item. I want it to move by pixels continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. The answer is to use another plugin if you want fluid scrolling, e.g. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/